# How to cancel mutlicall of componentDidMount() in ReactJS component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a component **DATA** which has **componentDidMount()** function to get data from the API. After this, I import it into the **main** component. The main component has a render method where I have a simple structure: 1st div - Some info and imported component DATA, 2nd div is a button which opens a modal, which has some text and button which closes this modal dialog box. 
I have read that **componentDidMount()** is called only once after the component is rendered. 
But when I push button to open my modal page at the same time **componentDidMount()** is called again.
What I need is that **componentDidMount()** don't run when I open the modal box. But run only when the page is rendered or refreshed.

**main** component

```
import React from "react";
import Modal from '../components/modal/form'
import Actions from '../data/Actions'

class MainPage extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {
            show: false,

        };

        this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this); 
        //this.setSearchTopStories = this.setSearchTopStories.bind(this);

    };

    showModal = e => {
        this.setState({
          show: !this.state.show
        });
    };



    render(){

        return <div>
            <div className="topDescribtion">
                <h2>descr</h2>
                <Actions />
            </div>
            <div className="btnNewTransaction">
                <button onClick={e => {
                    this.showModal();
                }}>
                    show Modal
                </button>
                <Modal onClose={this.showModal} show={this.state.show}>
                    Mdl--
                </Modal>
            </div>
            <div className="transactionList"></div>
        </div>
    }
}  
export default MainPage;
```

**DATA** component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Modal from '../components/modal/form'

const PATH_BASE = 'my URL which I give data in JSON format and it works fine';

class Actions extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            result:null
        };
        this.setSearchTopStories = this.setSearchTopStories.bind(this);
    }
    setSearchTopStories(result) {
        this.setState({ result });
    };
    componentDidMount() {        
        fetch(`${PATH_BASE}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => this.setSearchTopStories(result))
        .catch(error => error); 
    };
    render(){
        const { searchTerm, result } = this.state;
        console.log(result);
        return <div></div>;
    }
}

export default Actions;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The componentDidMount() method in Actions component is being called again as your parent component is re-rendered and so will the child. To stop this make your Actions component a Pure component instead.
A Pure component is only re-rendered when there is a change in state or props of that component.
**Replace**

```
class Actions extends React.Component{
```

**with**

```
class Actions extends React.PureComponent {
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: ok. yeah it help but some different thing now i see that console.log(result) in Actions component run twice when page start/refresh. 1st time it empty and 2nd time it have data which i need. is that a feature, but or  what?

Comment: render is mounted before componentDidMount(). So first-time empty coz api call has not been made yet. Then with the result coz api call is done and the state has changed.
If this answers your question please accept the answer and upvote it. So that other developers know the issue is resolved.